# Add a phrase before every character in a string

Tags: python

I have a string that comes from an input, for example, `"ABCD"`

I also have multiple strings `("0", "1", "2", "3")` that I want to add before each character in `"ABCD"`, such that the final result will be `"0A1B2C3D"`

I've tried using a dictionary and for loop:

```
text = input()
if len(text) > 4:
    return
phrases = {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"}
for i in range(len(text)):
    combined = []
    combined[i] = phrases[i] + text[i]
    print(combined[i])
```

But I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing out `combined` during every loop.  It never has any elements so even `combined[0]` is out of range.  You need to initialize it outside the loop, and then append the new data.  Also, you shouldn't print until you're done with the loop.

```
text = input()
if len(text) != 4:
    return
phrases = {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"}
combined = ''
for i in range(len(text)):
    combined += phrases[i] + text[i]
print(combined)
```

Or, better:

```
for i,c in enumerate(text):
    combined += phrases[i] + c
```

This could be even simpler if `phrases` were a list or a string.

Comment: One could also note that using `range(len(text))` to index `text` just after should be avoided

Comment: Which is exactly why I included the "Or, better" section.